# Extract particular schema from oracle dump file placed in file server

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, oracle-dump, oracle-export-dump

I have a complete data dump of all the schemas from my database in my local server, but I require a particular schema dump from the main dump file. I know the name of the schema for which I require a separate dump. Is there any way to get it?

I tried the following

> expdp User/pwd@db schemas=sample directory=/apps/dpdump dumpfile=sample.dmp logfile=sample.log

but I get the following error:

> UDE-00014: invalid value for parameter, 'directory'.

Answer (score 1):

Your schemas parameter looks correct, but the directory parameter is not.  The parameter actually refers to an Oracle DIRECTORY object, not the physical path itself.  You need to create the directory using the [CREATE DIRECTORY](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_5007.htm#SQLRF01207) command, example:

```
CREATE DIRECTORY MYDUMP AS 'apps/dpdump';
```

then reference that in the expdp command as, directory=MYDUMP  , etc.

You also may need grants and a synonym created on the directory depending on who needs access to it.

Comment: is there anyway of pointing the directory to local server and getting the schema dump, since i don't have permission to create the directory. Or is there any other way to extract a particular schema?